# Why am I still seeing installations for old versions of my app?

Tags: windows-dev-center

In the windows dev center, I am still seeing old versions of my app being installed - from the Analytics section.  I assumed that when I upgrade the package in the store, that the old packages no longer become available. Or is that not the case?

I've updated my package many times in the past month and the versions being displayed should no longer be downloaded and installed.  They wouldn't have been available in the store for much longer than one month.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a new package targeting a higher OS version and didn’t delete the previous package targeting an earlier OS version, then the previous package remains available to users using devices with earlier OS version.

For example, if you add a package targeting Windows 10 Mobile and keep your previous package targeting Windows Phone 8.x and earlier still over there, which means your app has two packages now, then users using Windows Phone 8.x still can get the previous package.

If you hope only the new package can be installed , then the old package need to be deleted.